# Airflow BigQuery Operator - Copying One Table to Another Table

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

Using the BigQueryOperator in Airflow, how does one copy a BigQuery table (with a schema of all strings) to another BigQuery table (with a schema of strings, integers and floats)? Note that table_1 and table_2 are already created in BigQuery with the below schemas, and the schemas for table_1 and table_2 should not change.

table_1 has the following schema and data:

```
Column_1 (string)  Column_2 (string)  Column_3 (string)  Column_4 (string)  Column_5 (string)
ABC                1                  1                  1.5                1
DEF                2                  2                  2.5                2 
HIJ                3                  3                  3.5                3
```

table_2 has the following schema and data:

```
Column_1 (string)  Column_2 (integer) Column_3 (integer) Column_4 (float)  Column_5 (integer)
ABC                1                  1                  1.5                1
DEF                2                  2                  2.5                2 
HIJ                3                  3                  3.5                3
```

To accomplish this task, I tried to use the following BigQueryOperator, but got an error message of 'Query column 2 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column Column_2, which has type INT64'.

```
BigQuery_Task = BigQueryOperator(
     task_id = "Copy_To_New_Table",
     sql = "INSERT `gcp_project.gcp_dataset.table_2` (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4, Column_5) SELECT Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4, Column_5 FROM `gcp_project.gcp_dataset.table_1`", 
     write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
     location = "US", 
     bigquery_conn_id = "conn_id",
     use_legacy_sql = False, 
     dag = dag)
```

Comment: Try removing:  `destination_dataset_table = "gcp_project.gcp_dataset.table_1"`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped but now getting an error message of 'Query column 2 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column Column_2, which has type INT64'.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove this part of the call:

```
 destination_dataset_table = "gcp_project.gcp_dataset.table_1
```

Then write a SQL command that will run.  BigQuery usually requires explicit conversions:

```
INSERT `gcp_project.gcp_dataset.table_2` (Column_1, Column_2, Column_3, Column_4, Column_5)
    SELECT CAST(Column_1 as int64),
           CAST(Column_2 as int64) as Column_2, 
           CAST(Column_3 as int64) as Column_3, 
           CAST(Column_4 as int64) as Column_4, 
           CAST(Column_5 as int64) as Column_5 
    FROM `gcp_project.gcp_dataset.table_1`"
```